# How can I do an auto SignOut if the session expires with Next-Auth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I've been learning React and Nextjs (with App Dir) for a couple of days and i have to build an MVP at work.

I want to implement that if the user is inactive in a period of time automatically signOut.

I set the maxAge of the session but when expires the thing that I tried didn't work and throw an error of session null because I read data from it.

I tried check the session in a layout and use redirect if its null but it didn't work and tried with a useEffect and call signOut but it generates a loop.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Take a look at this person asking a similar question on GitHub: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/6401